# Is it possible to prevent the user from using Safari on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, mobile-safari

I need to remove or at least make it impossible for the user to run Safari on an iPad.

Instead, the user should use a far more restricted browser that we will provide.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jailbreaking possibly, without jailbreaking, no.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can. Go to Settings > General > Restrictions, enable them, and turn off Safari. You can find more information on Apple's [website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to open url in your app by using your own webview instead of opening safari, you can register your class with the UIWebViewDelegate protocol and implement the method – webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
Inside this method, you can deal with the url and return NO, so that safari won't be opened.